Serving both php file and proxy pass to another app for iframe purposes
So, this has been plaguing me for a couple of weeks, and I am quite new at Nginx. So basically, I have an app made by using code igniter 3, served in /var/www/my-apps. My application has an OpenSearch (kibana) iframe embedded into it.
That IFrame is pointing to that OpenSearch (https://opensearchdashboards:5601/goto/%5C<DASHBOARD_IDs>?security_tenant=global.
The client requires it not to have a login screen. Now there are 2 ways to accomplish this, using anonymous_account but using the original link  the https://opensearchdashboards:5601/goto/%5C<DASHBOARD_IDs>, in the iframe
or injecting auth at nginx proxy using proxy_pass and proxy_set_header Authorization. And using my domain name https://myapp/goto/%5C<DASHBOARD_IDs, in the iframe
The first method is to work out of the box, but the client needs to have a connection to the backend, so the question is there a way for the client not to be connected to the backend?
Now it is the point my limited knowledge in nginx is showing. The second method, I think, the nginx is pathname is colliding with the way codeigniter 3 handles the URL.
The nginx server config

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  myApp.com;

         location = / {
           try_files /index.html =404;
        }

        location / {
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;

            proxy_pass https://opensearchdashboards:5601/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic <AUTH CREDENTIALS>";
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_send_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            send_timeout 600;
        }

       error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apache2 Index</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Embed TEST</h1>
        <iframe src="https://myApp/goto/<DASHBOARD_IDs>" height="600" width="800"></iframe>

</body>
</html>

Above are nginx and index.html that serving static index.html with embedded iframe, this is working if i only serve single static page
And below is the nginx and ci3/application/views/iframe.php when i am trying PHP with ProxyPass with sub URL of /dash/ to be proxy to opensearch back end
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name myApp.com;

        root /var/www/myApp;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust PHP version as needed
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /dash/ {

            proxy_pass https://opensearchdashboards:5601/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic <AUTH CREDENTIAL>";
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_send_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            send_timeout 600;

            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root /var/www/html; # Adjust if needed
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html; # Adjust if needed
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

The PHP for i frame is practically similar to HTML but just converted to php
So, how do i exactly both embed the iframe while serving my PHP file, many thanks
